# Debug Jar that is a Maven Dependency to a Main Project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have a project (client) that has as a maven dependency, a custom jar that the client uses to makes calls to.  I need to develop and debug that jar, and test them as I make calls from the client.

What's the best way in Intellij Idea 13 to do that?   Should I go to the "External Libraries" node on the client project, and change the library settings of the jar, so that instead of referencing the jar in my .m2 repository, I reference the actual jar in the Intellij target folder?

Comment: "I need to develop and debug that jar" - do you mean develop your code or develop the code from the jar?

Answer (score 0):

You can either put them into one maven project - create tree structure like

```
root pom.xml
-- client - pom.xml
-- library - pom.xml
```

This would make the development much easier due to common build.

If this is not feasible (e.g. library and client sit in different repositories) than open your client project and use "Add Maven project" (green plus) in Maven projects menu in intellij. In the dialog select your library project. It will add selected as module dependency to intellij.